# Spring amqp When there is network failure between rabbitmq server and consumer, AmqpIOException is thrown and no retry happens for consumer

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We are using Spring rabbitmq for out project. We are currently testing different failover scenario to prevent any further exception over Production.

We are using following properties:
    listener:
      type: direct
      direct:
        acknowledge-mode: manual

What we face is that When there is any network failure, we got following logs:

```
    INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 15:37:55,726] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:463) - Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#4c05df3b:0/SimpleConnection@2d361383 [delegate=amqp://workflow@192.168.156.53:5671/, localPort= 49445]
INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 15:37:55,789] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:613) - SimpleConsumer [queue=vishalr_dev.1482820471007_workflow, consumerTag=amq.ctag-TNSIb9kI1SxdO8cXtfOgrg identity=7155ef26] started
WARN  [AMQP Connection 192.168.156.53:5671][2018-10-22 15:38:08,830] - com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler.log(ForgivingExceptionHandler.java:115) - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
ERROR [AMQP Connection 192.168.156.53:5671][2018-10-22 15:38:08,836] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger.log(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1302) - Channel shutdown: connection error
ERROR [null-consumerMonitor-1][2018-10-22 15:38:12,285] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$null$3(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:397) - Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=vishalr_dev.1482820471007_workflow, consumerTag=amq.ctag-TNSIb9kI1SxdO8cXtfOgrg identity=7155ef26]
INFO  [null-consumerMonitor-1][2018-10-22 15:38:17,282] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:447) - Attempting to connect to: [montu.local.com:5671]
ERROR [null-consumerMonitor-1][2018-10-22 15:38:17,290] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$4(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:416) - Cannot connect to server
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:564) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:538) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:520) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1500(CachingConnectionFactory.java:94) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:569) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$4(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:413) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:847) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

After above log, it is not retrying to connect with consumer.

However we debug into spring jar itself and found that for org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException, it is not adding consumer for restart and it could be issue behind it.

Any idea , how we can resolve our network faiover scenario with this.

Here network failover means we have put firewall between rabbitmq server and consumer as a first test, as a second we have disable network adapter from consumer side.

**UPDATE : 1**
**=============================================================================**

*Reason behind why we are testing this type of network failur is that*, One day before we have some infrastucture issue, Due to which rabbitmq VM was down for 30min.

But when rabbitmq VM is running up again, All consumers was not connectted automatically as it should.  We tried to regenerate this in our local but couldn't. Here is log from instance where consumers was not able to auto connect.

```
INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 10:15:51,142] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:447) - Attempting to connect to: [RABBITMQAIND1.hqdev.india:5671, RABBITMQBIND1.hqdev.india:5671]
ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 10:15:51,142] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$5(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:459) - Error creating consumer; retrying in 5000
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:553) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.consumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:535) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$5(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:446) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:847) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 10:15:54,472] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:463) - Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#40ae8c5:85/SimpleConnection@54d6cde2 [delegate=amqp://workflow@192.168.154.191:5671/, localPort= 50085]
ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 10:16:07,314] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$5(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:459) - Error creating consumer; retrying in 5000
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:557) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.consumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:535) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$5(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:446) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1834) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1771) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1752) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:540) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$null$9(RabbitAdmin.java:453) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$10(RabbitAdmin.java:452) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:36) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:620) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:553) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:126) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:122) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:144) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:947) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:52) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:991) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.queueDeclare(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueues(RabbitAdmin.java:608) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$initialize$11(RabbitAdmin.java:542) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1828) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@RABBITMQAIND1' of durable queue 'collabscrum1.1454137672227_workflow' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:288) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:138) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@RABBITMQAIND1' of durable queue 'collabscrum1.1454137672227_workflow' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:504) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:643) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:581) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 10:16:07,345] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:593) - Queue not present, scheduling consumer SimpleConsumer [queue=neha_dev_workflow, consumerTag=null identity=5e8ed89c] for restart
java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:126) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:122) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:144) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:991) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:52) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:991) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:572) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.consumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:535) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$5(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:446) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@RABBITMQAIND1' of durable queue 'neha_dev_workflow' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:288) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:138) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@RABBITMQAIND1' of durable queue 'neha_dev_workflow' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:504) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:643) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:581) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1][2018-10-22 10:16:07,345] - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:593) - Queue not present, scheduling consumer SimpleConsumer [queue=autoind9.1526118175953_workflow, consumerTag=null identity=6465a7f8] for restart
java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:126) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:122) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:144) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:991) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:52) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:991) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:572) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.consumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:535) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$5(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:446) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
```

Is this log more useful to trace issue ?

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? It's working as expected for me (2.0.8.RELEASE) when the network is not available during startup...

```
2018-10-22 10:57:50.924  INFO 91651 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [10.0.0.88:5672]
2018-10-22 10:57:50.925 ERROR 91651 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Error creating consumer; retrying in 5000

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
```

and when disconnecting the network while running...

```
2018-10-22 11:08:02.729  INFO 93234 --- [nsumerMonitor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [10.0.0.3:5672]
2018-10-22 11:08:02.730 ERROR 93234 --- [nsumerMonitor-1] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Cannot connect to server

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
```

What hardware are you running on? - as you can see, I get a `AmqpConnectException` but you are getting an `AmqpIOException`.

**EDIT**

> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@RABBITMQAIND1' of durable queue 'neha_dev_workflow' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)

This means you are using a cluster but the queue is not mirrored (HA); after the failure, your connecting to a different node to the one that owns the queue (and that instance is not not running). If the node is running, it probably means the cluster is broken (you can see that on the overview page of the Admin UI) - each node thinks the other one is not running.

See [the rabbitmq documentation about recovering from a network partition](https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html).

I had a similar problem yesterday while testing your situation; I recovered it by restarting one of the nodes.

Comment: What version are you using? :
    name: 'spring-amqp', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    name: 'spring-rabbit', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'

What hardware are you running on?
   Window 10 
when the network is not available during startup...
  It is working fine in startup case.

But when there is already a connection established and network failure happens, then it is not retrying.


I had doubts about hostname & IP address, but I tried with Ipaddress also, but not working.

Comment: Also, after reading your comment, I tried network failure differently, I only get AmqpIOException in case disable network adapter.   When I remove my network cable from the local workstation, I am getting AmqpConnectException exception and also it is retrying as expected.

Comment: I have updated question with more details. Please have a look into it.

Comment: It sounds like your cluster experienced a network partition (which will happen if you disable a network adapter where rabbitmq is running) - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Yes, the cluster was broken, However, we have set autoheal as an option for network partition recovery.  It has recovered also as we checked both nodes of the cluster.  But what we face is that our consumer which was consuming message from different queues, we find out above logs and no consumer was auto connected to those queues. we have waited for a half hour but it did not get auto connected. But when we restart our consumer, then it connected successfully. is there any other option where we wouldn't have to restart any node or our microservices.

Comment: If you continue to get `Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@RABBITMQAIND1' of durable queue 'neha_dev_workflow' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)` after the partition is repaired, you should ask a question on the `rabbitmq-users` google group which the rabbit team monitors - it has nothing to do with Spring. I just tested here and it reconnected when the cluster was re-established.

Comment: Oh ok, No problem. we will communicate with them for this issue. Bdw if I use simple container then even after disabling network adapter it is retying to connect and on enabling it again, it connected successfully. I don't understand why it is failing for direct message container.

Comment: `> if I use simple container...connected successfully` - that makes no sense - please post a COMPLETE debug log showing the Direct container attempting to recover, including after the partitioned cluster is repaired.

Comment: Hi  Gary Russell, I am able to regenerate this specific issue. Lets say I have 5 queue connected with RabbitMq using spring amqp client. Now when the network lost happen and after it successfully restored, the first connected queue is not connecting again, out of 5 only 4 queues are connected. The same thing again happens if network failures happen, out of 4 only 3 queue is able to connect. If this network failure happens multiple times, then in last no queue is connecting..

Can you help me with this? Or I need to create another thread for this?

Comment: Ask a new question and provide much more information, logs etc.

Comment: Hi Gary, created a new thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879429/spring-amqp-consumer-not-re-connecting-to-queue-after-network-failure