# Spring amqp consumer not re-connecting to queue after network failure

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have a spring application which is having a dynamic queue listener connecting to queue in rabbitmq. Let's say I have a total of 5 listener consumer connected to 5 queues from my spring application to rabbitmq.

Now if Network fluctuation/failure happens then each time, first one of my 5 connected queues is stopped retrying to rabbitmq.

I have debugged code through spring-amqp class and found out that on creating a connection with rabbitmq (when network failure happens), it fails to connect to it and throw org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException particular exception which is not handled in retry function so that that queue is removed from retried queue list.

My Main class:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ClientAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.x.x.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.x.x.entities")
public class Main
{
    @PostConstruct
    void configuration()
    {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

        RabbitMQListenerUtil queueRegisterUtil = context.getBean(RabbitMQListenerUtil.class);

        try
        {
            queueRegisterUtil.registerSpecifiedListenerForAllInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Class which is used to create 5 consumer/listener

```
/**
 * The Class RabbitMQListenerUtil.
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RabbitMQListenerUtil
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public void registerSpecifiedListenerForAllInstance()
    {
        try
        {

            log.debug("New Listener has been register for instane name : ");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            registerNewListener("temp1");
            registerNewListener("temp2");
            registerNewListener("temp3");
            registerNewListener("temp4");
            registerNewListener("temp5");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will add new listener bean for given queue name at runtime
     * 
     * @param queueName - Queue name
     * @return Configurable application context
     */
    public void registerNewListener(String queueName)
    {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext childAnnotaionConfigContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        childAnnotaionConfigContext.setParent(applicationContext);

        ConfigurableEnvironment environmentConfig = childAnnotaionConfigContext.getEnvironment();

        Properties listenerProperties = new Properties();
        listenerProperties.setProperty("queue.name", queueName + "_queue");
        PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("props", listenerProperties);
        environmentConfig.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);

        childAnnotaionConfigContext.register(RabbitMQListenerConfig.class);
        childAnnotaionConfigContext.refresh();
    }

}
```

Class which create dynamic listener for queue consumer

```
/**
 * The Class RabbitMQListenerConfig.
 */
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMQListenerConfig
{

    /** The Constant ALLOW_MESSAGE_REQUEUE. */
    private static final boolean ALLOW_MESSAGE_REQUEUE = true;

    /** The Constant MULTIPLE_MESSAGE_FALSE. */
    private static final boolean MULTIPLE_MESSAGE_FALSE = false;

    /**
     * Listen.
     *
     * @param msg the msg
     * @param channel the channel
     * @param queue the queue
     * @param deliveryTag the delivery tag
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    @RabbitListener(queues = "${queue.name}")
    public void listen(Message msg, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long deliveryTag) throws IOException
    {
        int msgExecutionStatus = 0;
        try
        {
            String message = new String(msg.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            log.info(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error(e.toString());
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally
        {
            ackMessage(channel, deliveryTag, msgExecutionStatus);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ack message.
     *
     * @param channel the channel
     * @param deliveryTag the delivery tag
     * @param msgExecutionStatus the msg execution status
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    protected void ackMessage(Channel channel, long deliveryTag, int msgExecutionStatus) throws IOException
    {
        if (msgExecutionStatus == Constants.MESSAGE_DELETE_FOUND_EXCEPTION)
        {
            channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, MULTIPLE_MESSAGE_FALSE, ALLOW_MESSAGE_REQUEUE);
        }
        else
        {
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, MULTIPLE_MESSAGE_FALSE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bean will create from this with given name.
     *
     * @param name - Queue name- 
     * @return the queue
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue queue(@Value("${queue.name}") String name)
    {
        return new Queue(name);
    }

    /**
     * RabbitAdmin Instance will be created which is required to create new Queue.
     *
     * @param cf - Connection factory
     * @return the rabbit admin
     */
    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin admin(ConnectionFactory cf)
    {
        return new RabbitAdmin(cf);
    }

}
```

Application log :

https://pastebin.com/NQWdmdTH

I have tested this multiple times and each time my first connected queue is being stopped from connecting .

========================= **UPDATE 1**=============================

Code to reconnect stopped consumer :
https://pastebin.com/VnUrhdLP

Answer (score 0):

> `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmqaind1.hqdev.india`

There is something wrong with your network.

Comment: yeah as I mention there is network fluctuation happen during this. So this type of error is throwns.  It is just network lost for some time and again it comes back. But why our consumer is stopped from retying to connect?

Comment: Another instance which has a different exception as shown in here.
https://pastebin.com/wsTRXapH
in the above case, it stopped retrying to connect.

Comment: `Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@MICROSVC1A1' of durable queue 'prodqueue.1535968874507_queue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)` You are accessing a non-mirrored queue and the node that has that queue is down. By default, we stop trying after 3 attempts; you can increase the container's `declarationRetries` property and `failedDeclarationRetryInterval` (default 5000ms).

Comment: Our all queue are mirrored queue, also this queue was present over there with other 50+ queues, the node was also up as except this queue, other queues successfully connected. Still declarationRetries & failedDeclarationRetryInterval  property will required?  Also we are using DirectMessageListenerContainer.

Comment: No; you don't need `declarationRetries` with the direct container it will try forever. Well, the error is clear `is down or inaccessible` so clearly the node you are connected to can't access the queue - perhaps you have a split-brain cluster that needs to be fixed. If not, you should ask the RabbitMQ guys on the rabbitmq-users Google group what can cause this condition.

Comment: oh ok. But why it is the case when there is AmqpIOException only, it stopped retrying ?  As you can see in both scenarios, AmqpIOException is thrown.  However one more thing to add, when I tried this network connect and disconnect case with SimpleMessageListenerContainer, It successfully connect all the queue.it only fails with network fluctuation in DirectMessageListenerContainer. I can show you debugging code what is happening in spring amqp retrival process in this network failure ,making short video if you want?

Comment: I need to see a complete log from the error to the point where it stops retrying.

Comment: all logs from starting of application to the recreation of this issue, logs are here https://pastebin.com/NQWdmdTH

Comment: That's the log with the `UnkownHostException` I need the full log from your second comment from start to when the retries stopped.

Comment: Gary, I tried to get log for you but it is our production instance so due to security , i can not share that with you. However, We have found one solution to reconnect those stopped queues using some event.  Can you please look into that reconnect code : https://pastebin.com/VnUrhdLP?  We have use DirectMessageListnerContainer's stop and start method for it.   So is it good idea to use those methods?

Comment: pastebin.com/VnUrhdLP , this code works for us for reconnection, but just to confirm that is it good thing to use DirectMessageListenerContainer stop and start method for this purpose ?

Comment: Yes; that is fine.